# Operation with dates in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Hy, I am new to sql and I am trying to get the employees that have worked a complete number of weeks(integer). I have tried this :

```
SELECT employee_id, last_name, salary
FROM employees
WHERE MOD(ROUND(SYSDATE – hire_date), 7) = 0;
```

but I've got this error:

```
0911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual.
*
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Oracle sql developer.I am using with ubuntu

Comment: That's not a regular `-` you have there, it's some sort of dash. Delete it and re-type it. (And never copy/paste code or SQL from Word or other such text processors.)

Comment: @Mat Thank you, it worked! It was an exemple from a course and I wanted to see if it's working.

Comment: Note that this query will ignore indices (will be slow for large datasets).  If you have a Calender table, you can easily accomplish this with a join; remember that whole number of weeks means starting on the same day-of-the week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a "En Dash" (–, ascii code 150) in your `where` clause, instead of a hypen (-, ascii code 45), which is used as the subtraction operator.

One you replace it with the proper character, the query executes just fine:

```
SELECT employee_id, last_name, salary
FROM employees
WHERE MOD(ROUND(SYSDATE - hire_date), 7) = 0;
```